# Populating the Col1 and Col2 data in the Spark data frame, i have mentioned the input dataframe and expected dataframe in the Image attached

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

i am absolutely new to Spark , i have got this task where i am given the input with nulls in column 1 and col 2 , i have to populate based on the particular above column  values.

The Highlighted part is to be generated using pyspark,
That is just a sample data. Please feel free to use your own data. Thank you in advanc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import last, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Sample dataframe

data = [(1, "A", "B"), (2, None, None), (3, "C", "D"), (4, None, None), (5, None, None), (6, None, "E")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col0", "col1", "col2"])
df.show()

# To replace null values in col1 and col2 based on the values in the rows above them
df = df.withColumn("col1", last("col1", True).over(Window.orderBy("col0")))
df = df.withColumn("col2", last("col2", True).over(Window.orderBy("col0")))
df.show()
```

In this code, `last` function is used to fill in the null values in `col1` and `col2` with the values from the rows above them. The `Window.orderBy` function specifies that the values should be filled basis the order of the `col0` field.

**Input data:**

| col0 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | C | D |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  | E |

**Output:**

| col0 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | A | B |
| 3 | C | D |
| 4 | C | D |
| 5 | C | D |
| 6 | C | E |

Comment: Hi Aswin , what if the First column is not there , Col0  its not there in the Excel which my senior provided me

Comment: Hi Aswin , what if the First column is not there , Col0  its not there in the Excel which my senior provided me , can  i skip the window order by logic and try the same , i commented because , i will try today and if i failed i can come back here to see the posted answer. Thank you

Comment: Without sorting the data using window order by, it is not possible to find the previous row value

Comment: You should sort the data based on some column.

Comment: df2 = df.withColumn('index', F.monotonically_increasing_id()).withColumn('ID', F.first('ID', True).over(Window.partitionBy('Code'))).orderBy('index').drop('index')


thanks Ashwin  , i got this reply , will this be useful with our example

Comment: Yes, this code will create a column `index` temporarily and increasing unique value is assigned for each row. Then null value in the ID column is replaced with the first non-null value for each group of rows with the same Code value on the sorted index value.